# How to hide Photos from iOS

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

The new *OS X Photos App* allows to *hide* photos. *Hidden* photos will only appear in the `Hidden` album (or in any album which you explicitly added them to).

However, the *Hidden* photos keep showing on the *iOS Photos App*. *iOS* detects they are hidden, but it merely hides them from the image picker controller on third party apps. They can still be viewed in the main *Photos App* on the *All Photos* section. Is there any way to hide them from *All Photos* as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Hiding photos on iOS prevents them from displaying in Moments, Collections, and Years, but they will continue to show in any of the albums under "Albums".

Unfortunately, short of deleting them and then restoring them within 30 days, you are limited to the provision that Apple developed.

Comment: iOS 11 update: They are now hidden everywhere (even in Albums) except in a special "Hidden" smart folder.